# How to get xstring methods variables work with pgfmacros and vice versa in all situations?

Tags: tikz-pgf, pdftex, xstring

I am trying to draw simple graph with my command:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{xstring}
\usepackage{float}

\begin{document}
\newcommand{\lT}[4]{  \draw[line cap=round, line width = 0.5] (#1, #2) -- (#3,#4){}; }

\newcommand{\drawGraph}[1]{
\StrLen{#1}[\mylen];    
\foreach \x in {1,...,\mylen}
{
\pgfmathtruncatemacro{\second}{\x+1};
\foreach \y in {\second}
{
    \StrChar{#1}{\x}[\numA];        
    \StrChar{#1}{\y}[\numB];        
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\rA}{\numA * 0.5};
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\rB}{5 * 0.5};           % problem
    \lT{\x-1}{\rA}{\x}{\rB};        
}}}

  \begin{figure}[H]%
 \begin{tikzpicture}[font=\sffamily, scale=0.50, every node/.style=      {scale=1.00}]  

\drawGraph{1482449257683314302317851};

\end{tikzpicture}%
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Like this its draw something. problem is that if i change line:

```
\pgfmathsetmacro{\rB}{5 * 0.5};
```

to this:

```
\pgfmathsetmacro{\rB}{\numB * 0.5};
```

it's throw "! Missing number, treated as zero." err. Line with \numA is working... This is probably my tenth attempt with different code. I tryed: \newcounter, \newcount, pgfmacrosss, but always at some point there is same err. So what am i missing? thanks.

In one of my previous attempt i tryed without second foreach:

```
\StrChar{#1}{\x}[\numA];
\pgfmathtruncatemacro{\y}{\x + 1};      
\StrChar{#1}{\y}[\numB];        
\pgfmathsetmacro{\rA}{\numA * 0.5};
\pgfmathsetmacro{\rB}{\numB * 0.5};  
\lT{\x-1}{\rA}{\x}{\rB};
```

same err...

Comment: `\y` is not defined, because the `\foreach` loop uses `\yy` instead.

Comment: mistake..edited.

Comment: You haven't tested that code to make sure it compiles, have you? Please do so and correct it as required.

Comment: fixed, should be compilable now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`\x` takes the string length as last value:

```
\StrLen{#1}[\mylen];
\foreach \x in {1,...,\mylen}
{
```

Then `\second`

```
\pgfmathtruncatemacro{\second}{\x+1};
```

is larger than the string length, but

```
\StrChar{#1}{\y}[\numB];
```

`\y` is empty now, because `#1` does not provide any digits after the string end and the empty `\numB` is invalid in the multiplication:

```
\pgfmathsetmacro{\rB}{\numB * 0.5};           % problem
```

The error would be gone by providing an additional digit:

```
\StrChar{#10}{\y}[\numB];
```

But I do not know, what is intended, thus I cannot say, what the correct fix would be.

> [image: Result]

Comment: thanks a lot, at the end i decreased \mylen by one so \second woudn't go outside boundaries of string. thx.